# Would adding a value for every deleted value still maintain constant space?

Tags: big-o, space-complexity

Let's take this pointless function for example.. I add a value to the new array for every value removed from the old array. In the end, the memory usage would yield an array of the argument array length in addition to an empty array. Is this considered O(1) space complexity?

```
const constantSpace = (array) => {
    const newArray = [];

    let i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) {
       newArray.push(array.pop());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity would be O(N) where `N` is the length of the array.

One way to look at this is: if you change the length of `array` from 10 to 10,000 to 10,000,000 will there be any change in memory required to represent that array? The answer is yes, your memory usage will increase linearly as the length of `array` increases.

Depending on the language and actual data type for `array` and `newArray` (are they staticly allocated arrays, or a dynamically sized data structure that grows and shrinks over time?), you would end up with somewhere between `N` and `2 * N` in total array length available (if you added up `array.length` + `newArray.length`). If the original `array` does not shrink as elements are removed from it, you would end up with `2 * N` total array elements.

For space complexity to be O(1), that would be something like a single integer variable that stores one value. You could write 10 different values to it in succession or 10,000,000 and the memory required would not change.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you throw away the temporary internal array at the end of your "calculation", and the memory size of the "result" is constant, your code still needs space for that array to run to completion, so the memory complexity of your function remains `O(N)`.